# Javascript error in Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
 var xmlHttpReq = getXmlHttpObject();
    xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            var res =xmlHttpReq.response;     
            var result = res.split(',');           
            if (document.getElementById("shoppingCardAjax")!=null){      
            document.getElementById("shoppingCardAjax").innerHTML = overAllPayment + result[1];
            }
    }
```

on Chrome this code works flawless, but on Mozilla 3.6 I'm getting error:

```
res is undefined
var result = res.split(',');
```

Why? What's the difference?

Comment: The last version of the piece of software called "Mozilla" was 1.7.13. Do you mean Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlHttpReq.response` should be `xmlHttpReq.responseText`

PS: Why don't you use a nice lib like jQuery instead of doing all the XHR stuff manually?

Comment: Nice, but can you explain why?

Comment: Simply because the correct attribute is `responseText` (i have no idea why Chrome has `.response`, too)

Comment: Interesting. Chrome has an alias for `responseText` called `response`: [Here's a test (presumably only works on Chrome)](http://jsbin.com/eseli3/2) Color me surprised! Neither [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx) nor the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#xmlhttprequest) defines that. Just check Firefox 3.6, Opera 11, and IE9, none of them has it.

Comment: MSDN is not really a good resource for JS things - better use [MDC/MCN](https://developer.mozilla.org). We all know what Microsoft often thinks about standards..

Comment: Since Microsoft invented `XMLHttpRequest`, this would be one of the times it's worth looking at MSDN -- not for information on the *standard* (that's what the W3C link was for), but on their version of the object.